# Prevent Printing a worksheet unless a defined Macro function is clicked

Tags: vba, excel, printing

I have a format designed in Excel, kind-of an Invoice and I enter the particular cells....... and then, through a Macro function, (I assigned one to a box shape) add those entered cells onto another Workbook called as 'Database'.. Only then would I like to print. Possibly even warn with 'msg' if thee step is not done. I hope I'm clear. 
 My concern is that the page being printed might be faked.. like for instance I fill out the form, then print it... then edit particular cells and then I add it to the database. So the values aren't matching and hence I've successfully created a fake document right? That's what I want to prohibit.

Comment: You are saying that no printing (of workbook/worksheets) should be allowed except via a button box shape click?

Comment: You'll need to utilize `Workbook_BeforePrint`. See [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1802-excel-prevent-printing-sheet.html)

Comment: Note that whatever you do, printing worksheets is a feature of Excel. If I open the file with macros disabled, whatever VBA code you've written to try to prevent me from printing the worksheet won't run, and I'll be able to print it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

- Make a "macro" which writes to a specific cell in a specific worksheet. Make sure that the worksheet is with a `.VeryHidden` visibility. Something like this:

---

```
Public Sub AllowPrinting()
    Worksheets(1).Range("A1") = "SomePassword"
End Sub
Public Sub BanPrinting()
    Worksheets(1).Range("A1") = ""
End Sub
```

- Use `BeforePrint` event in the `ThisWorkbook`. The `Cancel = True` part disables printing.

---

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Worksheets(1).Range("A1") <> "SomePassword" Then Cancel = True
End Sub
```

[BeforePrint MSDN](http://%20https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-beforeprint-event-excel)

Answer (score 0):

Use the BeforePrint event. For a brief introduction to events, I recommend: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/events.aspx. Your code would have to be inside the workbook module and would look like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)

   macro_to_run_before

End Sub
```

Or, alternatively, you could use an If to check if the macro was executed.

Comment: Ok so I have to copy paste my 'Macro recorded code' into 'macro_to_run_before' ? that way would I be preventing someone from printing the doc unless he/she has clicked the button for e.g. in my case 'Add to Database'?

Comment: This way you will ensure that the macro is run before it is printed (so you don't need to check it). This seemed more useful to me than checking if the code was run before.